# Limit of sequence of growing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Let

$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$

$K_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$ and consider the sequence of matrices defined by
$$
K_L = \underset{2^{L}\times 2^{L}}{\underbrace{\left[H\otimes I_{2^{L-2}}\right]}}\underset{2^{L}\times 2^{L-1}}{\underbrace{\left[I_2 \otimes K_{L-1}\right]}}\in\mathbb{R}^{2^L\times 2^{L-1}},
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

I am interested in the limiting behaviour of the singular values of $K_L$ as $L$ tends to infinity. Some calculations indicate that the $2^L\times 2^{L-1}$-matrix $K_L$ has $L$ non-zero singular values and that the empirical distribution of those nonzero singular values converges to some limit. Can this limit be described in terms of the matrix $H$?

I am wondering if it is possible to use some kind of fixed-point theorem to characterise the limit (in any sense) $\lim_{L\to\infty}K_L$ as an operator on some sequence space.

---

**Edit:**
I did some more experiments and it seems that the limiting behaviour of the singular values of $K_L$ does not only depend on the matrix $H$, but also on the initial value $K_1$.

To illustrate this, let $K_1(\alpha)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ \alpha\end{array}\right)$ and consider the sequence
$$
K_L(\alpha) = \left[H\otimes I_{2^{L-2}}\right]\left[I_2 \otimes K_{L-1}(\alpha)\right].
$$

The largest singular value of $K_{10}(\alpha)$ is depicted in the following figure. (The graph looks essentially the same for all $L\geq 4$ instead of $L=10$.)

[image: The largest singular value of <span class=]$K_{10}(\alpha)$" />

The minimum is approximately $(-.2936,0.7696)$.

This makes it unlikely for fixed-point arguments to work in this setting. I, therefore, modify my question and ask if the limiting behaviour of the singular values of $K_L$ (or $K_L(\alpha)$) can be characterised directly in terms of $H$ and the initial value $K_1$ (or $K_1(\alpha)$).

**Edit 2 (March 2015):**
As the question is still receiving attention, let me add that I came up with a conjecture for the asymptotic behaviour of the singular values of $K_L(\alpha),$ as detailed in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117513/singular-values-of-sequence-of-growing-matrices).

Comment: Could one propose a formulation in terms of tensors of an increasing rank over 2-dimensional vector space? My intuition is jammed with this Kronecker product stuff, but I’ll possibly understand something when saw tensors.

Comment: I do not think that I could contribute, but do the brackets in the definition of $K_L$ denote something special? Or are they just for emphasizing that the Kronecker product is evaluated before the matrix multiplication?

Comment: @flawr It's only that Kronecker product is evaluated before the matrix multiplication

Comment: Does kind of resemble this other question involving Haar Wavelets, if multipling whole matrix by -1 before conversion : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198335/potential-uses-for-viewing-discrete-wavelets-constructed-by-filter-banks-as-hier

Comment: This has been answered on MathOverflow, should it be deleted here then?

Comment: What was the motivation for this problem?

Comment: Your question has answers on math overflow. Here is the link: https://mathoverflow.net/q/117513

Comment: Since the question has been answered on MO, shouldn't this post be closed?

Comment: @acephalous. Yeah I think it should.

Comment: I tried to flag it as such, but my flag was declined. Not sure what the procedure is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has been answered on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117513/singular-values-of-sequence-of-growing-matrices

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered on MO.

Comment: I am closing this question, as it has been answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117513/singular-values-of-sequence-of-growing-matrices .  I am also placing a historical lock on this question---it is highly upvoted, which seems to indicate that the community values it.