# Scaling for characteristic polynomial of sequence of growing matrices

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a follow-up question to [Limit of sequence of growing matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258736/limit-of-sequence-of-growing-matrices).

There I was considering a sequence of matrices defined by
$$
K_L = \left[H\otimes I_{2^{L-2}}\right]\left[I_2 \otimes K_{L-1}\right],
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad K_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right).
$$

I was interested in understanding the singular values of the matrices $K_L$. Experimentally I observed that the characteristic polynomial $\chi_L\in\mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$ of $K_LK_L^T$ scales with $\lambda^{2^L}$, in the sense that $\lambda^{2^L}\chi_L(1/\lambda)$ converges pointwise to a limiting function as $L$ tends to infinity.

I am now trying to generalise this observation to other matrices $H$; the easiest example I could come up with is
$$
H'=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad K_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\  0\end{array}\right).
$$

Like for $H$ the rows and columns of $H'$ sum to one and each row also occurs as a column. Nonetheless I seem to be unable to find a scaling such that the characteristic polynomial of $K_LK_L^T$ based on this larger matrix $H'$ converges to a limit.

My question is therefore:

> Does such a scaling exist? If so, how can I find it for more general matrices $H$?

**Edit:**

Even for the (apparently simpler) $4\times4$ initial matrix
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{array}\right),\quad K_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)
$$
I can't find the correct scaling for the characteristic function. Any advice on this problem?