# Block eigenvalue decompositions with strictly positive elements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk, canonical-transformation

In the similarity transformation $$\cases{{\bf A = T}^{-1}{\bf DT}\\ {\bf D}_{ij} = \lambda_j\delta_{i-j}}$$

The *eigenvalues* $\lambda_j$ of $\bf A$ are on the diagonal in $\bf D$, and corresponding eigenvectors are the columns in $\bf T$. For some $\bf A$ matrices we can't find such a pair of $\bf T,D$ but instead we can get a block diagonal decomposition. Typical things that can affect if we can find such a similarity is what kinds of numbers we allow the matrix elements to be. If we allow complex numbers, which are in some sense more complicated than real numbers, then we can diagonalize more matrices than if we only allow real numbers. But if we allow blocks of real numbers on the diagonal we can once again find similarity.

Now to the question: In the spirit of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198335/potential-uses-for-viewing-discrete-wavelets-constructed-by-filter-banks-as-hier), can we go in the opposite direction, disallowing negative reals (or replace them with 2x2 blocks of *non-negatives* like in the other questions) and be able to create a block-diagonal "eigenvalue" decomposition? Or rather, **under which circumstances** (properties of $\bf A$ et.c.) would we be able to do it?

If we could characterize it. Maybe we would be able to define some kind of canonical basis for diffusion or random walks.

Comment: Firstly, it should be $A=TDT^{-1}$, if the *columns* of $T$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. Secondly, are you interested in ($\mathbb{C}$-)diagonalizable matrices, only? What if the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue does not equal the algebraic multiplicity, i.e. if there are Jordan-blocks of size $>1$ in the Jordan normal form of $A$?

Comment: No. If multiplying from the right with column vector it should indeed be $A = T^{-1}DT$, eigenvectors being columns in $T$ and $D$ diagonal.

Comment: If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$, then $Av_1=v_1\lambda_1$ and $Av_2=v_2\lambda_2$. This can be written as $A(v_1\;v_2) = (v_1\;v_2) D$ which in turn is $AT = TD$ or $A=TDT^{-1}$

Comment: I want $D$ all non-negative real elements and in distinct blocks along the diagonal. I.e. what to demand of $\bf A$ to get that.

Comment: Why being offensive? Try to follow my argument and try to find out what is wrong about it. Then you will see that I'm right. If you still have doubts about $A=TDT^{-1}$ you could also take a look at [Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors).

Comment: Am I being offensive? It is your attempt at distraction that is being offensive to me. Just create a diagonal matrix $D$ and $T$ and $T^{-1}$ and see for yourself what happens.