# A matrix probability distribution machinery that changes over time - (how) does it work?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, markov-chains

It is well known we can represent Markov chains using matrices $\bf P$ and vectors $\bf p$ of probability densities.

But what can we do if we have a **second degree chain** in this sense:

$$\text{Rule for update} \cases{\bf p = Pp\\\text {vec}({\bf P}) = {\bf P_2}\text{vec}(\bf P)}$$

In other words we treat the $\bf P$ matrix as a vector that is affected by it's own Markov chain once every time after $\bf p$ is affected by $\bf P$.

What must we demand of $\bf P_2$ for this to be well defined? And more importantly how could we analyze it and what could we model/build with it?

---

**A minimal example**:

A givens rotation $${\bf R} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right], a^2+b^2=1$$
can be combined with [this positivization procedure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198335/potential-uses-for-viewing-discrete-wavelets-constructed-by-filter-banks-as-hier) and a renormalization produce the following $${\bf P_2} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}a&0&b&0\\0&a&0&b\\0&b&a&0\\b&0&0&a\end{array}\right]$$

Which we can renormalize to make it stochastic by ensuring $a+b=1$ or just simply multiply the matrix with a renormalizing diagonal matrix afterwards in case it is not.

---

Can we analyze the consequences of this construction with just linear algebra or do we need something more powerful?