# Convolutions with complex numbers turned into markov chains. What probabilistic properties can we derive?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, soft-question, convolution, signal-processing

I have [this old question on probabilistic interpretations of filterbanks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198335/potential-uses-for-viewing-discrete-wavelets-constructed-by-filter-banks-as-hier) I have not completely figured out yet. However some time afterwards I realized it is possible to extend even further to complex numbers and make more general to convolutions and not only filterbanks. Since the complex numbers are an **algebraically closed field** I was thinking maybe we can derive some more interesting properties for the markov chains given the properties of those numbers.

The mapping I had in mind is:
First step the classic $2\times 2$ representation matrix for complex numbers : 
$$a+bi \to \left[\begin{array}{rr}a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right]$$
And the second step being the same as the mapping for $\mathbb R$:
$$a\to \cases{ \left[\begin{array}{cc}a&0\\0&a\end{array}\right], a >0\\\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right], a<0}$$
In total giving us ( for each complex scalar ), the block of real non-negative scalars:

$$a+bi \to \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}a&0&0&b\\0&a&b&0\\\hline b&0&a&0\\0&b&0&a\end{array}\right]$$

can we use some property related to complex numbers to help derive how block-convolution matrices consisting of such blocks ( circulant or Toeplitz for example ) will behave in terms of probability theory.

---

**EDIT** As promised to Did, a connection to the tags used **signal processing** and **probability theory**:

In signal processing a very common tool/operation is **linear & time invariant filtering**. If the time discrete **signal** is represented by a vector with a scalar for each time point, then the convolution can be carried out with multiplication by a [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) or [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix depending on if the convolution is **circular** or not. Now our construction is remapping **scalars** used in the filters in these matrices to blocks so we get block-matrices. Now after we have done this we can rescale the matrix by normalizing to get row sum of 1. That way we get a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) which has many properties in probability. Now if we transform the scalars in the signal into blocks by the same method, we can start treating the filtering as a probabilistic process described by [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Example of **circulant** and *Toeplitz* matrices for filter with scalars $[1,2,3]$, designed to work on a vectorized signal of length $6$:

$$ {\bf C} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}1&2&3&0&0&0\\
0&1&2&3&0&0\\0&0&1&2&3&0\\
0&0&0&1&2&3\\3&0&0&0&1&2\\
2&3&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right], \hspace{1cm} {\bf T} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}1&2&3&0&0&0\\0&1&2&3&0&0\\0&0&1&2&3&0\\0&0&0&1&2&3\\0&0&0&0&1&2\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: (probability-theory)? Where? (signal-processing)? Where?

Comment: @Did: Markov chains have lots of probability theory. Convolutions and filter banks are extremely central to signal processing.

Comment: Yeah, but nothing of these is appearing in the present question, is it?

Comment: I can edit to clarify the connections a little bit later if it is unclear.