# Linear recurrence for number of n-step paths in finite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

I am interested in finding linear recurrences for the number of n-step paths between two fixed vertices in a finite graph. The question is motivated by the same problem that led to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258736/53115).

For concreteness' sake, let's consider the graph $G$ on 16 vertices given by the adjacency matrix
$$
M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

```
M={{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}};
```

This directed graph has constant out-degree 4, some self-loops, und looks like this:
[image: Graph on 16 vertices]

From counting paths in the graph directly, or computing powers of $M$, one finds that the numbers of $n$-step paths from $1$ to $1$ are given by

```
n      #paths      paths
-------------------------
1      1           1-->1
2      2           1-->1-->1, 1-->10--->1
3      6           1-->1-->1-->1, 1-->1-->10-->1, 1-->10-->1-->1, 1-->10-->10-->1, 1-->9-->12-->1, 1-->2-->14-->1
4      24
5      100
6      408
7      1640
8      6560
9      26224
10     104864
...    ...
```

Experimentally, we find that the number of $n$-step paths, $a_n$, satisfy the linear recurrence
$$
a_n = 6\,a_{n-1} -10\,a_{n-2} + 8\,a_{n-3},\quad n>3,
$$
e.g., for $n=4$, 
$$
24 = 6\times 6 - 10\times 2 + 8\times 1 = 36-20+8=24.
$$

Looking back from the end of an $n$-step path beginning and ending in $1$ it is clear that the number of such paths equals the sum of $(n-1)$-step paths beginning in $1$ and ending in any of the predecessors of $1$, that is in ${1,6,10,11,12,13,14,16}$, but from there things seem to get messy.

Similar recurrences, some of length 3, can be found for the number of $n$-step paths between any two vertices in this graph.

I believe that a simple random walk on this graph (with the sinks $7$ and $16$ removed) with uniform transition probabilities is an aperiodic irreducible Markov chain, and so counting the number of paths of terminating in a specific vertex would allow to compute the stationary distribution without solving an eigenvalue problem.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1) Are linear recurrences between number of $n$-step paths a general feature of finite graphs or are their specific to this example?
>
> 2) What determines the order of the recursion?
>
> 3) How can one compute the coefficients in the recurrence? Is it easier or harder than (or incomparable to) solving the eigenvalue problem of $M$?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

First of all I assume you're counting "paths" where repeated nodes are allowed.  I.e. the no. of $n$-step paths from $i$ to $j$ is simply the $(i,j)$ entry of $M^n$, which I will denote $M^n_{ij}$.

Let $v =$ no. of nodes, i.e. $M$ is size $v \times v$.

Since $M^n = M \times M^{n-1}$, we trivially have a system of $v^2$ recurrences: each recurrence expresses one of the $v^2$ values of $M^n_{ij}$ as a linear combination of the $v^2$ values of $M^{n-1}_{ij}$.  (Each linear combo has at most $v$ non-zero terms, but I am not sure this helps.)  Based on this alone, I'm 90% sure we can rewrite the recurrences s.t. each $M^n_{ij}$ is a linear combo of $M^k_{ij}$ where $k \in \{n-1, n-2, \dots, n-v^2\}$.  I.e. by isolating each $(i,j)$ variable, you can get a recurrence in each $(i,j)$ variable that looks back at most $v^2$ steps in time.  (I am only 90% sure this is doable, not 100%.)

Now of course in your case $v^2 = 16^2 = 256$, so this theoretical process (even if it works) does not explain how you can get recurrences in $M^n_{11}$ (what you called $a_n$) that looks back only $3$ steps in time.

Furthermore, I would think that if there is a path $i \to j$ that is e.g. $7$-hops long, then its contribution won't even show up until $n=7$.  E.g. if the shortest $i \to j$ path is $7$-hops, then $M^n_{ij} = 0$ for $n < 7$, so no recurrence on $M^n_{ij}$ can look back fewer than $7$ time steps.  Given your specific graph has many $1 \to 1$ paths that are quite long, I'm surprised you can write a recurrence that looks back only $3$ time steps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, repeated nodes are allowed in the path counting iff there is a self-loop at that node. I agree that the low order of the recurrence seems particularly surprising.

Comment: What do you mean repeated nodes are allowed iff there is a self loop?  What about bigger loops?  E.g. in your graph, $1 \to 10 \to 1 \to 10 \to 1$ should be a perfectly valid $4$-hop path even though no self-loop was used in that path.  (And calculating based on $M^4$ would certainly include that path.)

Comment: Sorry, by "repeated node" I meant to refer to the same node being both the start and the end of a step in the path, such as 1-->1. I think we agree that an $n$-step path is just a sequence of not necessarily distinct nodes $v_{i_1},...,v_{i_{n-1}}$, such that $M_{i_j, i_{j+1}}=1$ for $j=1,...,n-1$.